# Is there any option in matlab to optimize (row,column) in order to show subplots?

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have to plot different graphics with subplot within a figure but I do not know how many will be plotted because it depends on the data introduced by the user (for loop). In order to plot a subplot I need to know the number of columns and rows. Is there any option in matlab that matlab configures the best number of columns and rows to display plots knowing the total subplots to do? I mean subplot(a,b,c) => best a,b combination knowing c.

Now I ask to the user to introduce number of columns and rows but it's a bit uncomfortable. Maybe an algorithm to take a decomposition of the total subplots into the 2 most equals factors should work but I think it's quite difficult to code that. If it's too complex I'll follow with my way but I was curious about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in solution; what has been working well for me in practice is the following approach, where I try to get a nearly square arrangement with a few more columns than rows (because of wider-than-tall screen aspect ratio):

```
nRows = floor(sqrt(nPlots));
nCols = ceil(nPlots/nRows);
```